# Sending token from and to smart contract

Tags: solidity

I created smart contract where I send token from contract to senders wallet. 
I also want contract to receive tokens and send back ETH. In what way can I find out how much tokens sender sends to smart contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing an ERC20 smart contract you have to write the `transfer()` function. The parameters are

- `_to` destination of tokens
- `_value` value of tokens sent

This is the implementation part of the [SingularDTV contracts](https://github.com/ConsenSys/singulardtv-contracts/blob/master/contracts/StandardToken.sol#L13)

```
/*
 *  Read and write storage functions
 */
/// @dev Transfers sender's tokens to a given address. Returns success.
/// @param _to Address of token receiver.
/// @param _value Number of tokens to transfer.
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The user has to call your `transfer()` function. You can add the rest of the logic in the function.

Comment: This helps, thanks.
And how can I send ether from funds wallet to sender?
Is it possible to withdraw ether from funds wallet and send it to address that sent tokens?

Comment: To send ether from your contract you can `_to.transfer(etherValue)`